Contraction of $(-1)$ curve and extremal ray
I want to prove Castelnuovo's contraction theorem by Mori's contraction theorem.

Question. How can one show that a $(-1)$ curve on a smooth surface is an extremal ray?


In general, if $C$ is an irreducible curve on a smooth surface $X$ such that $C^2 \leq 0$ then $[C]$ is in the boundary of $\overline{NE}(X)$, and if $C^2 <0$ then $[C]$ is extremal in $\overline{NE}(X)$.
See Lemma 1.22, p. 21 in
J. Kollár, S. Mori: Birational geometry of algebraic varieties, Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics 134, Cambridge University Press. viii, 254 p. (1998). ZBL0926.14003.

Thanks a lot!!!

@George, if you like and find useful Francesco's answer, accepting it is perhaps a nice thing to do.
